# Looking For A CMS Mainly For Static Content Publishing

Tags: content-management-system, cdn, document-management

I am tasked to research and evaluate a long overdue CMS system for our dept within a large software company.  For the most part we need a system that has workflows and the ability to publish static content to a specified location (app server, cdn etc...).  We aren't interested in a typical CMS that let's you create templated websites.  Our developers will still be creating our applications in their preferred language and will ideally pick up the static content that will populate areas of our websites from the CMS to avoid code deployments for every little content change.

Another department is doing this using Teamsite.  Aside from Teamsite can anyone here recommend a CMS?  I'm not too impressed with their interface (and their price tag).  I found a product called Ingeniux that does what we need (multi format output) but I haven't heard much about them and need to demo their system.

While this is our main requirement, other requirements would be - average price tag (free to $20k, rather than +$100k a year), self hosted (not a hosted or cloud solution), and straightforward setup and integration process (ideally we don't want to hire a consulting company to stand up the servers etc...).

Thanks.

Comment: is open-source and ruby a viable option?

Comment: sure - open source is doable.

Answer (score 3):

You could

1. put some of that money to fund one of this open source projects
2. ask the author to do custom work for you
3. allocate time for one of your coders to learn the technology and implement and maintain the tool you need by an open-source project.

I used, with satisfaction, for some of my work:

Ruby

- [NANOC](http://nanoc.stoneship.org/)
- [Jekyll](http://github.com/mojombo/jekyll/tree/master)
- [Webby](http://webby.rubyforge.org/)
- [Middleman](http://middlemanapp.com/)
- [Ruhoh](http://ruhoh.com)
  ...And a bunch of other solutions from [this](http://nanoc.stoneship.org/docs/1-introduction/#similar-projects) big list at Nanoc website.

Node.js + Coffescript

- [DocPad](http://docpad.org)

Also try [this lightweight cms using ruby and google drive](http://spin.atomicobject.com/2012/11/16/a-lightweight-cms-using-ruby-and-google-drive/) nice alternative.